# Emit event through nested components in Angular2

Tags: angular

One can use `Output()` decorator to emit the event from the child component so that the parent component can catch it. What I need is to catch an event emitted by any child component, which is not necessarily a direct child of a given component.

Let `ComponentTwo` be a component which emits the event. If the app has the following structure: `App -> ComponentTwo`, then we can easily catch the event emitted by `ComponentTwo`. But if we consider structure like `App -> ComponentOne -> ComponentTwo`, then we can't catch the emitter directly.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3vaXFFhT9FRcKbLGHRig?p=preview) that illustrates the problem.

So is there a way to sort of propagate event to all parent components? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a different approach using `CustomEvents` rather than `Outputs()` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wv8p5
Details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68784117/1277159 :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no support of bubbling for such events. You need to manually catch them and emit to the parent.

Another approach would be to leverage a shared service for this tree of components and use an observable / subject in it.

This way all components can subscribe on it to be notified of events even within sub sub children.

```
constructor(private service: SharedService) {
  this.service.notifier$.subscribe(
    data => {
      (...)
    });
}
```

The event will be triggered this way:

```
constructor(private service: SharedService) {
}

notify() {
  this.service.notifier$.next('some data');
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thank you. BTW is absence of bubbling due to design of A2 or just not implemented (yet)?

Comment: The direct link has changed. It is now:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

Answer (score 1):

If you find you have to pass certain events through make sure to be consistent and come up with a naming strategy. For instance I like to add `raise` to the beginning of the method name if the only thing that method does is to re-raise an event.

eg.

```
(paypalTokenized)="raisePaypalTokenized($event)"
```

and in the `ts` file:

```
@Output('paypalTokenized')
public paypalTokenizedEmitter = new EventEmitter<PayPalTokenizedPayload>();

// PayPal tokenized
public raisePaypalTokenized(payload: PayPalTokenizedPayload)
{
    // no other logic here!
    this.paypalTokenizedEmitter.emit(payload);
}
```

This means I can tell immediately that the event is being passed through with no further action.

Comment: Or alternatively you can just directly emit the event:


(paypalTokenized)="paypalTokenizedEmitter.emit($event)"

Answer (score 0):

the thierry answer is the correct aproach, but if you want to avoid use shared service, you can do somthing like this

view.html

```
<componentA
   (actionA)=actionHandler($event)
>
</componentA>
```

view.ts

```
actionHandler(event){
  //doSomething
}
```

componentA.html

```
<componentB
   (actionB)=actionHandlerA($event)
>
</componentB>
```

componentA.ts

```
@Output() actionA: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {
}

actionHandlerA(event){
  this.actionA.emit(event);
}
```

componentB.html

```
<a (click)="actionHandlerB(...)" >click me</a>
```

componentB.ts

```
@Output() actionB: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {
}

actionHandlerB(o: objectModel){
  this.actionB.emit(new objectModel(o));
}
```

Comment: Nice sample. It worked for me. Thanks!