# Angular: How do I emit an event up through multiple nested components?

Tags: angular

I have one "smart" component called **ItemsComponent** and two nested "dumb" components, **ItemsListComponent** and **ItemComponent**.

**ItemsComponent**'s html template contains **ItemsListComponent**.

```
// ItemsComponent
<div>
  // ItemsListComponent
  <app-items-list
    [items]="items"
    (doDelete)="deleteItem($event)"
  >
  </app-items-list>
<div>
```

and it has a function called **deleteItem**:

```
deletItem(item) {
  // code to handle item deletion...
}
```

**ItemsListComponent** contains **ItemComponent**:

```
// ItemsListComponent    
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
  // ItemComponent
  <app-item
   [item]="item"
   (doDelete)="deleteItem($event)"
  >
  </app-item>
</ul>
```

So the html structure is like this:

```
ItemsComponent (app-items)
    - ItemsListComponent (app-items-list)
        - ItemComponent (app-item)
```

**ItemComponent** has a button

```
<button (click)="deleteItem(item)">
```

and an event emitter for **deleteItem**:

```
@Output() doDelete = new EventEmitter();

deleteItem(item) {
  this.doDelete.emit(item);
}
```

When the delete button is clicked in **ItemComponent**, the event only bubbles up to it's immediate parent, **ItemsListComponent**, but doesn't make it to **ItemsComponent** unless I add identical event emitter functionality to the **ItemsListComponent**.

Smelly **ItemsListComponent**:

```
@Output() doDelete = new EventEmitter();

deleteItem(item) {
  this.doDelete.emit(item);
}
```

It works this way, but **ItemsListComponent** now shares code smell with **ItemsComponent** since they both have the same event emitter stuff and the event has to be passed from one component to another on it's way up.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emit event through nested components in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073415/emit-event-through-nested-components-in-angular2)

Comment: Yes, @echonax I think you're correct.

Comment: I think this is one of those code smells you just get used to over time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you've realised, custom angular events don't bubble, so if you have a deeply nested component and you want to pass an event to a higher component, every component in between has to delegate the event upwards.

Another option is to move your `deleteItem` functionality to a service that is injected into one of your lower level components. That way, the function can be called at the point where it happens, rather than having to bubble the event up your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you can make it happen using a `CustomEvent` rather than an `EventEmitter`. This is just a workaround, especially because Angular communication patterns are well described in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) and many other [places](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-angular-components-communicate-pass-emit-or-broadcast-data-4-ways-with-examples/).

Basically, you need to trigger a `CustomEvent` from the inner child and simply listen for it on the outermost component (the grandparent).

**OutermostComponent**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'outermost',
 template: `<child></child>`
})
export class OutermostComponent {
      @HostListener('FormSubmitCustomEvent', ['$event'])
      onCustomEventCaptured(event: any) {
        console.log('Event Received', event.detail);
      }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<inner-child></inner-child>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
   
}
```

**InnerChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-child',
  template: `<button (click)="onSubmit()"></button>`
})
export class InnerChildComponent {

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

onSubmit(): void {
    const event: CustomEvent = new CustomEvent('FormSubmitCustomEvent', {
      bubbles: true,
      detail: { data: 'Hello from Inner Child' }
    });

    this.elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Here's a working blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wv8p5

Comment: very cool and sexy answer

Comment: Instead of ```@HostListener('FormSubmitCustomEvent', ['$event'])``` in parent, you can also use it as norml event in html eg. ```<button (FormSubmitCustomEvent)="handleSubmit($event)">```