# Angular - emitted event doesn't get through to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

I'm trying to emit an event from a child component to a parent component.
Here is part of the parent file TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-detail',
  templateUrl: './car-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-detail.component.css'],
})
export class CarDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCarDetail(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }

  refreshList(event){
    console.log("Parent called");
  }
}
```

And part of the template that concerns the emitter

```
<app-operations (myEvent)="refreshList($event)"></app-operations>
```

Here is the child TS file:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-operation',
  templateUrl: './add-operation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-operation.component.css']
})
export class AddOperationComponent implements OnInit {


  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  callParent() {
    console.log('callparentmethod');
    this.myEvent.emit('eventDesc');
  }

}
```

and a button to test call the callParent method:

```
<button (click)="callParent()">call</button>
```

When I click the button, I can see that the callParent method is triggered, but the method that should be triggered in the parent (refreshList) isn't. I looked at multiple examples and don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I see that the child component's selector is `app-add-operation` but you're providing `app-operations` in the template. Is this an issue or is something missing in the question?

Comment: This was the issue. I messed up because car-detail is the parent of operations which is the parent of add-operation and got mixed up, my bad, stupid mistake.

Comment: I recommend deleting this question since it's not very useful for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view is referencing the wrong component. Try this:

```
<app-add-operation (myEvent)="refreshList($event)"></app-add-operation>
```

Answer (score 2):

Event Emitters only affects the direct parent of the component, so you'll need to bubble the event from app-add-operation to app-operation and then app-car-detail.

See [Emit event through nested components in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073415/emit-event-through-nested-components-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this function on your child component.you can refer this doc [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

```
 myEvent(event: any) {
     console.log(event);
  }
```